# Mouse position with Ajax in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

Is it possible to post an Ajax request with a mouse position in PHP?
For e.g. i'm fetching a page in cUrl, and on this page I would like to post a mousemovement event.

I have no code yet and am looking at the function [**`ncurses_getmouse`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-getmouse.php) but there is minimal information about it.

Comment: Yeah, of course you can. Are you having problems with your code? If so, show the code ... if not, write some code.

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, then I don't think you can.

Comment: Have no code yet, also looking at the function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-getmouse.php but there is minimal information about this function.

Comment: There's [zero results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ncurses_getmouse) for this function here at [so]! Anyway, there's one example of usage at php.net, why don't you try to implement it?

Comment: at least try to find code over the internet and share your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for getting mouse position and posting request:

```
$("#target").mousemove(function(event) {
  $.post("test.php", {x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY});
});
```

If you need help with doing something with position in PHP, you can ask me.