# Mouse click position php

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel-5

I would like to get the position object sent to php.

html:

```
onclick="name(event)">
```

js:

```
function name(e)
{
      $.ajax({
        url: '/...',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'x': JSON.stringify(e)}
      });
}
```

php:

```
json_decode($request['x'])->pageX; // doesn't work
```

How can I read the position of this object?
I use laravel.

Comment: I don't understand what JSON has to do with this

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode($request['x']));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3234977/4454454)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Track mouse position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245147/mouse-position-with-ajax-in-php?rq=1

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't return anything useful with event objects. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` and you'll see.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547672/how-to-stringify-event-object

Comment: Why don't you use `data: { x: e->pageX, y: e->pageY }`